# SVN log parsing tool

Tags: svn

SVN records which files were change in each commit. But I want to know what functions were changed in each commit.

Ideally, I'd like to provide a method that gets called with each diff and then can save off which methods were changed in that commit.

Does such a tool or api exist?

Comment: The tool chosen is most likely language-dependent. I've seen some tools (eclipse w/svn) which parses commits and notes changed methods/properties/classes within that commit, but that is specifically one commit and java.

Comment: You can write your own log parsing tool with SVNkit http://svnkit.com/  There may be other SVN libraries in other languages.

Comment: (a) what do you mean, "that gets called with each diff" (b) what is the language these functions you are looking for are written in (c) is a bash script ok for you?

Answer (score 4):

SVN knows nothing about your programming language; so it can only show you the textual differences between files using e.g. `svn diff`.

But some IDE's know more of your language of choise, and e.g. Eclipse has a brillant "compare editor" that can highlight the differences between two files versions.

If you need something that works from the command line, and for which the output can be used in the logic of scripts, etc. - we need to know more about your programming language and requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use the svn hook post-commit script to modify the log of the version you are updating and add the result of the command svn diff.

[In this chapter from the SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch05s02.html) they talk about this scripts. [Here](https://gist.github.com/tfnab/1577891) you can find an example that sends the diff by email.